# java main() being static how it can have an access to non-static members of class?

Tags: static

In java, static methods can access only static variables then as main() is static and class contains static and non-static variables too then how come main() being a static can have access to non-static members of class?

Answer (score 0):

Add an instance:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    ThisClass tc = new ThisClass();
    tc.nonStaticVar//do whatever
}
```

This does not retrigger main because it isn't called.